# Incorrect coverage from istanbul with mocha in react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs, istanbul

#### Background

My project comprises of:

- an `app/` directory with `jsx` and `js` (including `*.test.js`) files
- npm script that invokes instanbul:

`babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.spec.js\" --delay --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive`

- I would estimate that in reality I have ~3-5% code coverage

#### Problem

When I run the report the numbers are much higher:

```
======== Coverage summary ======== 
Statements   : 93.24% ( 193/207 )
Branches     : 41.67% ( 10/24 )
Functions    : 92.45% ( 49/53 )
Lines        : 94.12% ( 192/204 )
```

Perhaps instanbul is not counting `jsx` files as I have:

- ~2500 LOC of `jsx`
- ~600 LOC of `js`

Could anyone offer insight into the config - thanks

#### Edit 1

I added a `.instanbul.yml` file and it improved things, but it still seems way too high:

```
#.instanbul.yml
instrumentation:
    root: app/
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

Output:

```
======== Coverage summary ========
Statements   : 74.85% ( 372/497 )
Branches     : 32.84% ( 44/134 )
Functions    : 84.21% ( 64/76 )
Lines        : 75.3% ( 372/494 )
```

### Edit 2

I used *isparta* and tweaked my `.istanbul.yml`:

```
babel-node isparta cover --include \"**/*.js\" --include \"**/*.jsx\" _mocha -- \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.spec.js\" --delay --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive
```

Outputs:

```
===== Coverage summary =====
Statements   : 87.7% ( 934/1065 ), 46 ignored
Branches     : 82.11% ( 413/503 ), 137 ignored
Functions    : 94.17% ( 194/206 ), 30 ignored
Lines        : 77.88% ( 419/538 )
==================================
```

### Solution + Change of strategy

I also needed to exclude tests in `.instanbul.yl`:

```
instrumentation:
    root: app
    excludes: ['*.spec.js']
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

Initially I was surprised that coverage was still so high. But that is because by and large, most of the code is is actually to do with rendering/lifecycles. This code is executed whenever the test environment (shallow) renders a component (using enzyme).

This indicates is I need a slight change of strategy. I will probably come up with another class of *behavioural* test (`*.bvr.test.js`) which will be designed to mirror the user stories. This will be a separate code coverage report.